# Call javascript function from WPF browser application (xbap)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, xbap

I am loading my `xbap` app into iFrame in a `.aspx` page. On button click in `xbap` application I want to call a JavaScript function which is in a page where `xbap` is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, you have to do something like this in your xbap when you call your javascript function

```
dynamic script = BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript;
script.document.javaScriptFunction();
```

and your javascript function looks like this

```
document.javaScriptFunction = function (){ your code here }
```

This method is working for all version of IE.